Animating Seamless Page Transitions in React with Next.js (and updating URLs)
For a project within our organization, we are developing an app using React (preferably Next.js). The UX team has designed an animation for the transition between two pages with different URLs. In the screenshot, you can see an example from Spotify. The URL needs to be updated as users navigate to the next layer. This is important because end users should be able to directly access the new layer via a link.
The problem, as shown in screenshot 2, is that the content of the first layer disappears immediately. To keep it simple, I used the same layer in this animation. I should have the option to have two elements where I can specify which one should be updated. And I don’t know if that’s possible.
If possible I would like to create the animations using the framer-motion package (although this is not a must-have).
In the screenshot, you can observe that the first layer remains visible while the second layer (with dynamic content) slides in. Once this second layer is closed, the first layer is still there.
In the 
I have been searching for hours for a solution for Next.js and also for vanilla React. However, I haven’t found a solution yet. Hopefully, someone can help me with this.

Is there a way to isolate the animation part into a separate component and use that as a wrapper around the two other components, firing off the animation on route change?

I don't understand your solution. Can you clarify?
I updated my question to make the issue clearer. I addedd 'The problem, as .... know if that’s possible.'

Are you considering installing a new library to your project or do you want to do it from scratch without importing a third party library?

The chosen solution doesn’t matter much to me. The project still needs to be fully developed, so we are open to all options. I came across Framer Motion as a good animation tool. That’s why I’m looking into it.
